# Access denied (401.2) when loading default documents using Owin with Identity 2.0

Tags: authentication, iis, forms-authentication, document, identity

We recently converted a Framework 4.8 WebForms project that was using Forms Authentication to use Identity 2.0 Authentication and now we can't access default documents or images without allowing anonymous access.

Once authenticated with Identity, if you browse to a folder such as http://mysite/dashboard/default.aspx it works fine. However, if the default page is not in the path as in http://mysite/dashboard/ it returns 401.2 as though IIS needs permissions to server the page :

> *Access is denied. Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be
> configured for access to the requested URL.
>
> Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server
> configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory
> or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication
> methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's
> administrator for additional assistance.*

We have `<authentication mode="None">` which I understand is correct for this situation. IIS is configured to use default documents just as it was when we were using Forms Authentication.

We also deny unauthenticated users with the `System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule`:

```
<authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

If we allow anonymous on the folder it does work but we don't what anonymous access on these locations.

```
<location path="Dashboard">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

So, how do you configure IIS to access default documents without 'allow anonymous' so it works like it did under Forms Authentication.

Thanks!!!

Comment: It looks like a way to solve this is to check the request in Owin for a root path and add in the default document. Not sure if that's how everyone is doing it but it seems like it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Found that adding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` to the `web.config` resolved the issues. Not really sure why at this point. I did notice that the request for a static file did not include the user identity which was working before removing Forms Authentication. After adding this, the user identity started showing up in the request.

Comment: This worked for me, having a custom authentication with OWIN cookie (without Identity) for SSO between ASP.NET and aspnet core. The problem was to use UrlAuthorization to protect static files when not logged in. If I only removed and re-added the module, the login wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to the `System.Webserver` section

```
<modules>
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
   <add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule"  />
</modules>
```

The key seems to be to remove the managedHandler Precondition from the FormsAuthentication module. As I understand it this is only supposed to optimize serving of static content.

Comment: Thanks for that but we already have that in our web.config.